# How to change the space between the itemize "items" in LaTeX?

Tags: spacing, lists, itemize

How to change the space between the itemize "items" in LaTeX so that I can continue to use the "itemize" and "item" tag without needing to redefine any new tags?

Comment: This question contains a solution much more elegant than those listed in the duplicate.

Comment: Argh, another instance of somebody erroneously closing a question. The "original" question asks how to do this globally, but this question asks how to do it at all.

Comment: Funny how the closed questions are usually the most useful ones ..

Answer (score 525):

`\itemsep` is the length you'll want to change.

As an example:

```
\begin{itemize}
  \setlength\itemsep{1em}
  \item one
  \item two
  \item three
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: You use it like this: `\begin{itemize} 
\itemsep0em 
\item one
\item two
\item three
\end{itemize}
`

Comment: Or, you change it with \setlength or \addtolength.

Comment: Don't do that. Just use the `enumitem` package as described in the answer this question is a duplicate of.

Comment: How would I use `\setlength` to affect whole document?

Comment: @71GA With the `enumitem` package, see here for instance: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4974583/1216878

Comment: Please note that you can also use negative values `\setlength\itemsep{-0.5em}`

Comment: @TH. `enumitem` won't work in the beamer environment.

Comment: @71GA @FooBar Redefine `itemize`. `\let\olditemize=\itemize \let\endolditemize=\enditemize \renewenvironment{itemize}{\olditemize \itemsep0em}{\endolditemize}`

Comment: @MartinThoma Instead of `\setlength\itemsep{-0.5em}`, is there a way to specify a clearpage or newpage for each item to start on a new clear page?

Comment: @71GA Define a new command as ```\newcommand{\bi}{\begin{itemize}\setlength{\itemsep}{1em}}```

Comment: @chan1142 I think your solution can even be simplified to `\let\olditemize\itemize \renewcommand{\itemize}{\olditemize\itemsep0pt}` -- i.e. since `\begin{itemize}` uses `\itemize` internally (more info [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26245)).