# Global setting of spacing between items in itemize environment for beamer

Tags: beamer, spacing, lists, itemize

I'd like to modify the spacing between items in the itemize environment.  [This](http://dcwww.camd.dtu.dk/~schiotz/comp/LatexTips/LatexTips.html#tweaklist) post shows how to modify a specific itemize environment (`\addtolength{\itemsep}{0.5\baselineskip}`).  However, I'd like to do it globally for the entire document.  [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12373/how-to-change-the-space-between-the-itemize-items-in-latex) post suggests the enumitem package.  However, I get an error in beamer when i use this package (just declaring it).  Any suggestions?  I'm currently using the addtolength method on all my itemize environments.  I'd like a global solution.  Thanks.

Comment: Related question [beamer: how to increase space between bullet and text in itemize environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63158/10478)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In most documents, you can do this, which avoids the use of extra packages.

```
\let\tempone\itemize
\let\temptwo\enditemize
\renewenvironment{itemize}{\tempone\addtolength{\itemsep}{0.5\baselineskip}}{\temptwo}
```

(Stufazi suggested a neater way of doing this in his answer, which I will use below.)

However, I think that the `frame` environment in `beamer` resets the properties of `itemize`. You could do something like this, but it will prevent `frame`'s optional arguments from working.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\let\oldframe\frame
\renewcommand{\frame}{%
\oldframe
\let\olditemize\itemize
\renewcommand\itemize{\olditemize\addtolength{\itemsep}{100pt}}%
}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item The first.
\item The second.
\item The third.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
%
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item The fourth.
\item The fifth.
\item The sixth.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
%
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, you could try this, but I can't guarantee that it won't break something else.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newlength{\wideitemsep}
\setlength{\wideitemsep}{\itemsep}
\addtolength{\wideitemsep}{100pt}
\let\olditem\item
\renewcommand{\item}{\setlength{\itemsep}{\wideitemsep}\olditem}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item The first.
\item<2-> The second.
\item<3-> The third.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
%
\begin{frame}[shrink=50]
\begin{itemize}
\item The fourth.
\item The fifth.
\item The sixth.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
%
\end{document}
```

It might be safer to define your own list environment based on itemize and use this in future; thus

```
\newenvironment{wideitemize}{\itemize\addtolength{\itemsep}{100pt}}{\enditemize}
```

This would avoid the necessity for hacks that have unwanted side effects.

Comment: I am a user of the wideitemize environment. When I have them nested though, I cannot change the font size of the inner one using `\fontsize`. only the outer one. Do you know why this might be the case?

Comment: @luchonacho --- I would guess it's a grouping issue. I suggest asking a new question about this, with an example code for others to play around with. It shouldn't be too difficult to fix this, once we see exactly what you are doing (famous last words).

Comment: Actually, it has nothing to so with the new environment. Question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/569624/77895

Answer (score 22):

Just put the two line in your foredocument (change the 100pt to any value you want):

```
\let\OLDitemize\itemize
\renewcommand\itemize{\OLDitemize\addtolength{\itemsep}{100pt}}
```

And if next time you write your document using the `enumitem` package (recommended!), you could

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setitemize{itemsep=100pt}
```

Comment: @Michael enumitem does not work with beamer as I've described.

@Stufazi this did not work for me.  I placed it right after

\documentclass{beamer}

Comment: Thanks for `\setitemize`, worked for me.

Comment: or you can use `\usepackage{enumitem}` and then `\begin{enumerate}[itemsep=100pt] ...`

Comment: it is possible that this interacts poorly with the bracket arguments after `\begin{itemize}` like `[<+->]`? The first solution causes a `missing \item` error in code that compiled previously. This is my best guess.

Answer (score 16):

After diving a bit into beamer's source files, I think that I've found the best way to implement this without breaking other options or advanced features of the `itemize` or `frame` environments. The solution is to define a new frame option like:

```
\makeatletter
\define@key{beamerframe}{wide}[30pt]{%
  \def\beamer@cramped{\itemsep #1\topsep0.5pt\relax}}
\makeatother
```

So that one can later write:

```
\begin{frame}[wide]
% ...
\end{frame}
```

to get “wider”, more spacey, versions of all the `itemize`, `enumerate` and `description` environments used in the frame. This is actually just a copy from another `squeeze` option already defined by beamer, so I'm guessing this would be the “proper” way to implement this without breaking anything.

---

### Set as default

One would also want, probably, an option to make this the default for *all* frames. Unfortunately beamer does not seem to support setting default frame options. The following *is* a bit of a hack, but I'm hoping it not to break anything. Throw all of this code in a style file (say `beamer-extra.sty`):

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{beamer-extra}[2013/08/22 Some extra beamer features]
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}

% A command to set default frame options:
%   \defaultframeoptions{<options>}  % append some more defaults options
%   \defaultframeoptions*{<options>} % clear past defaults, set some new
\def\beamer@extra@frameoptions{}
\def\beamer@extra@setframeoptions#1%
  {\appto\beamer@extra@frameoptions{\setkeys{beamerframe}{#1}}}
\def\defaultframeoptions{\@ifstar
  {\def\beamer@extra@frameoptions{}\beamer@extra@setframeoptions}
  {\beamer@extra@setframeoptions}}
\define@key{beamerframe}{environment}%
  {\def\beamer@frameenvironmentsubst{#1}\beamer@extra@frameoptions}

% A new frame option for wider items
\define@key{beamerframe}{wide}[30pt]{%
  \def\beamer@cramped{\itemsep #1\topsep0.5pt\relax}}
```

And then use it like:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamer-extra}
\defaultframeoptions{wide=15pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Example}
\begin{itemize}
\item One
\item Two
\item Three
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you

Comment: Also works for `note` (`beamernotes`)

Answer (score 8):

Another solution that works with beamer is to redefine `\item` as suggested [in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44349/21118) to a related question:

```
\let\olditem\item
\renewcommand{\item}{%
\olditem\vspace{4pt}}
```

This puts a space after items, even when they are followed by sub-items, unlike solutions based on `\itemsep`.

Rather than using a fixed size, this solution can be used with `\fill` so that the items (and sub-items) are spread out to fill the slide:

```
\let\olditem\item
\renewcommand{\item}{%
\olditem\vspace{\fill}}
```

This is useful for squeezing space when you want to put a bit more on a slide, or stretching space when a slide doesn't have so much content, so both look reasonable (within limits!).

Comment: This changes the spacing between items but breaks arguments after `\item` like `\item<+->`.

Answer (score 8):

As the other answers show, it is quite viable to redefine the environments to your liking. A more beamer specific approach would be to have templates take care of these settings.

There are predefined templates available, that allow us to modify the behaviour of `itemize` and `enumerate` environments alike. The following 6, one per line, can be used to decorate these environments.

```
itemize/enumerate body begin
itemize/enumerate body end
itemize/enumerate subbody begin
itemize/enumerate subbody end
itemize/enumerate subsubbody begin
itemize/enumerate subsubbody end
```

The `sub` and `subsub` templates are used for nesting these environments. The `body begin` templates, and especially the `itemize/enumerate body begin` template, can be used to "globally" set item-spacing in itemize (and enumerate) environments for beamer.

(Currently) Beamer starts our subject environments like this

```
\usebeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate body begin}
\list{redacted}{redacted}
\beamer@cramped
\raggedright
\beamer@firstlineitemizeunskip
```

For nested environments it uses the `subbody`-versions of the template.

Let's focus on the internal macro `\beamer@cramped`: Currently, using only the beamer class and styles as provided by the beamer package, this macro is either empty, or `\itemsep0pt\topsep0.5pt\relax`. At least `\itemsep` is one of the settings we are looking for and it is a `list`-specific (and therefore `itemize` and `enumerate` specific) setting. Apparently this macro was introduced exactly for the purpose we are looking for!

This means we are unlikely to break anything, by modifying this macro. We can write templates like this:

```
\defbeamertemplate*{itemize/enumerate body begin}{myAwesome theme}
{
    \let\this@beamer@cramped\beamer@cramped
    \renewcommand{\beamer@cramped}{
        \this@beamer@cramped
        \addtolength{\itemsep}{.5\baselineskip}
    }
}

\defbeamertemplate*{itemize/enumerate body end}{myAwesome theme}
{
    \let\beamer@cramped\this@beamer@cramped
}
```

I constructed this code in order to fit the question. Personally, I don't do the `\let` and `\addtolength` things. I simply define `\beamer@cramped` to set `\itemsep` to an absolute value, i.e.

```
\renewcommand{\beamer@cramped}{\itemsep2em\relax}
```

I keep the `\relax` at the end of my `\beamer@cramped` definition, because the original authors of `\beamer@cramped` probably had a reason to put it there in the first place.

The tricky thing is that we need to set `\itemsep` after `\list` is called, which means, we cannot simply set `\itemsep` in the template. By modifying `\beamer@cramped` we can put our code at a useful position.

It is possible that all of this happens inside of groups, so that our redefinition of `\beamer@cramped is only effective for a specific environment and its nested environments, I didn't investigate.

Comment: Can I use `\renewcommand{\beamer@cramped}{\itemsep2em\relax}` without defining a new theme? I've tried doing ``\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate body begin}{\renewcommand{\beamer@cramped}{\itemsep2em\relax}}`` but it doesn't quite work.

Comment: Yes, you can redefine `\beamer@cramped` without defining a new theme.

Answer (score 2):

A way of achieving a similar result, without using extra packages is this:

```
\renewcommand<>{\item}{\beameroriginal\item\vspace{\stretch{.2}}}
```

Although you will loose the ability to put overlay specification in the `\item`. Overlay specs still work in the environment options, though.

Answer (score 0):

I simply used this settings before the document starts:

```
\let\realitemize\itemize
\let\endrealitemize\enditemize
\renewenvironment{itemize}{%
    \footnotesize\realitemize\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt plus 1pt}}
    {%
    \footnotesize\endrealitemize%
    }
```

Here, I additionally decreased the font size to \footnotesize which is optional.
The spacing is adjusted with \parskip and \itemsep to achieve optimal goals!