# Line spacing for all enumerate / itemize blocks (beamer)

Tags: beamer, itemize, line-spacing

I just wonder, how it is possible to increase the spacing between between each bullet-item (item line) using beamer?

Is it possible to adjust the line spacing with defbeamertemplate or setbeamertemplate?

Thank you so much!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: \itemsep works for beamer as well as most document classes.

Answer (score 8):

I believe `\itemsep` is reset at the start of each `itemize` or `enumerate` and is given different values for different levels or when cramped.  For a global value, see [Global setting of spacing between items in itemize environment for beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16793/global-setting-of-spacing-between-items-in-itemize-environment-for-beamer?rq=1)

[image: beamer frame]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item Here I go again
\item creating a MWE\itemsep=2em
\item for a first timer.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```