# Set itemize default settings in preamble

Tags: spacing, formatting, itemize, preamble, vertical-spacing

If I want itemize always in this format

```
   \begin{itemize}
            \setlength{\parskip}{3pt}
            \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt plus 1pt}
            \item ...
    \end{itemize}
```

How could I do? How could I set up `\setlength{\parskip}{3pt}` and `\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt plus 1pt}` by default?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16793/global-setting-of-spacing-between-items-in-itemize-environment-for-beamer):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%------------------------------------
\let\tempone\itemize
\let\temptwo\enditemize
\renewenvironment{itemize}{
\tempone
\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt plus 1pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{3pt}
}
{\temptwo}
%------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item First item
\item Second item
\item Third item
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```