# Is there a reason to use \begin{environment} \end{environment} rather than \environment \endenvironment?

Tags: environments

What reason (other than perhaps being easier for my syntax highlighter to parse) is there to write

```
\begin{center}
Here is centered text
\end{center}
```

rather than:

```
\center
Here is centered text
\endcenter
```

And likewise for other environments. Does the `\begin` do any extra funky checks or are they effectively synonymous?

Comment: See the very related question [Defining environments based on other ones: What's the right way?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14683/defining-environments-based-on-other-ones-whats-the-right-way)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`\begin` and `\end` build a group, which can keep settings local. Simply writing `\command ... \endcommand` doesn't. Such a scope is very important for me, that's why I prefer the `\begin ... \end` syntax.

Example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\bfseries Text
\end{center}
text % this is normal font, left aligned as default
\center
\bfseries Text
\endcenter

text % this is still bold! and it's even centered
\end{document}
```

Comment: If `\endcenter` doesn't end centering, what _does_ it do?

Comment: @doncherry: It ends the triv-list used for centering `\endcenter: macro:->\endtrivlist`. The `\trivlist` apparently depends on the group added by `\begin` .. `\end` to revert the changes made.

Comment: Some environments actively support the "plain form", e.g. `\pgfpicture` .. `\endpgfpicture`, because they add a group by themselves.

Answer (score 10):

From `latex.ltx`:

```
\def\begin#1{%
  \@ifundefined{#1}%
    {\def\reserved@a{\@latex@error{Environment #1 undefined}\@eha}}%
    {\def\reserved@a{\def\@currenvir{#1}%
     \edef\@currenvline{\on@line}%
     \csname #1\endcsname}}%
  \@ignorefalse
  \begingroup\@endpefalse\reserved@a}
\def\end#1{%
  \csname end#1\endcsname\@checkend{#1}%
  \expandafter\endgroup\if@endpe\@doendpe\fi
  \if@ignore\@ignorefalse\ignorespaces\fi}
```

`\begin` defines (locally) `\@currenvir` and `\@currenvline`, starts a group and sets `\@endpefalse`; `\end` checks `\@currenvir` against its argument (throwing an error if they don't agree) and does other management tasks. It's not only the grouping. On the other hand, `\environment` and `\endenvironment` can be (almost always) safely used in the definition of another environment. There are a few topics on TeX.sx about this.

Comment: Regarding using `\environment` and `\endenvironment` in the definition of another environment: that's mostly true, though scoping could also be a issue here, producing undesired results in the end code.

Comment: The `\@currenvir` macro  `\begin{env}...\end{env}` will give an error when environments are improperly nested.  That's worth making more explicit.

Answer (score 8):

Further to [Stefan's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26245/is-there-a-reason-to-use-beginenvironment-endenvironment-rather-than-envir/26246#26246), here is the definition of `\begin` and `\end` from [`latex.ltx`](http://ctan.cdpa.nsysu.edu.tw/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx), clearly showing the grouping (`\begingroup` and `\endgroup`):

```
\def\begin#1{%
  \@ifundefined{#1}% Environment begin
    {\def\reserved@a{\@latex@error{Environment #1 undefined}\@eha}}%
    {\def\reserved@a{\def\@currenvir{#1}%
     \edef\@currenvline{\on@line}%
     \csname #1\endcsname}}%
  \@ignorefalse
  \begingroup\@endpefalse\reserved@a}% <- grouping starts
\def\end#1{% Environment end
  \csname end#1\endcsname\@checkend{#1}%
  \expandafter\endgroup\if@endpe\@doendpe\fi% <- grouping ends
  \if@ignore\@ignorefalse\ignorespaces\fi}
```

In contrast to that, defining a new environment merely executes (in some order, depending on optional parameter specification):

```
\def\newenvironment{\@star@or@long\new@environment}
\def\new@environment#1{%
  \@testopt{\@newenva#1}0}
\def\@newenva#1[#2]{%
   \kernel@ifnextchar [{\@newenvb#1[#2]}{\@newenv{#1}{[#2]}}}
\def\@newenvb#1[#2][#3]{\@newenv{#1}{[#2][{#3}]}}
\def\renewenvironment{\@star@or@long\renew@environment}
\def\renew@environment#1{%
  \@ifundefined{#1}%
     {\@latex@error{Environment #1 undefined}\@ehc
     }\relax
  \expandafter\let\csname#1\endcsname\relax
  \expandafter\let\csname end#1\endcsname\relax
  \new@environment{#1}}
\long\def\@newenv#1#2#3#4{%
  \@ifundefined{#1}%
    {\expandafter\let\csname#1\expandafter\endcsname
                         \csname end#1\endcsname}%
    \relax
  \expandafter\new@command
     \csname #1\endcsname#2{#3}% <- \<env>
     \l@ngrel@x\expandafter\def\csname end#1\endcsname{#4}}% <- \end<env>
```

From the definition of `\@newenv` (I've added some comments), `\newenvironment{<env>}{<begin-env>}{<end-env>}` assigns `<begin-env>` to `\<env>` and `<end-env>` to `\end<env>` without any sign of grouping.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to everything else: `\endfoo` need not be defined in order for the `\end{foo}` to work, see everybody who uses size commands as environments and gets away with it (to some extent).