# Increase the spacing between my paragraphs while maintaining the spacing between items in the itemize environment

Tags: spacing, itemize, parskip

I tried to increase the spacing between my paragraphs by using the `parskip` package but it also increased the spacing between my items in my `itemize` environnment.

How do I change the spacing between my paragraphs without changing the spacing between my items?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage[skip=1.5\baselineskip, indent=0pt]{parskip}


\begin{document}
Hermitian operators have the following properties:
\begin{itemize}
    \item The eigenvalues are real
    \item The eigenfunctions are orthogonal
    \item The eigenfunctions of any Hermitian operator is complete, meaning that any function can be represented by a linear combination of the eigenstates.
\end{itemize}

But this means that we have no idea what the momentum is. Hence, classically speaking, we cannot say exactly where the particle would be at a later time because we don’t know where it is heading and how fast. 

If the elapsed time is not so long, then the particle will be reasonably expected to be found near the starting point. But other than that, we cannot say where the particle is exactly located at any later time.
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance for your answers !

Comment: You can use [package `enumitem`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg) to configure the itemize environment, e.g., using option `nosep` or setting `itemsep=0pt` (depending on what you want).

Comment: You can also comment the package and set manually `\parindent` to 0pt and `\parskip` to some enough to see the difference (e.g. `3em plus 1em minus 1em`). Note that this can also influence other structures as the ToC, but you can set manually both values not only in the preamble but also locally inside a  group (`{...}`) or environment.

Comment: The solution from PaulRein here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12373/how-to-change-the-space-between-the-itemize-items-in-latex